# Python: What am I doing wrong in PyClutter?

Tags: python, ubuntu, clutter

I was redirected but I have another problem now:

```
import cluttergtk
import clutter
import gtk
import time
lasttime=1
lastbin=1
lastbout=0
black =clutter.Color(0,0,0,255)
red =clutter.Color(255, 0, 0, 255)
green =clutter.Color(0,255,0,255)
blue =clutter.Color(0,0,255,255)
def updatespeed(t, a, b):
    global lasttime, lastbin, lastbout
    f=open('/proc/net/dev','r')
    for line in f.readlines():
        line=line.strip()
        if (line[:4] == 'eth0'):
          line=line[5:].split()
          bin=int(line[0])
          bout=int(line[8])
          timedelta=time.time()-lasttime
          lasttime=time.time()
          speedin=round((bin-lastbin)/(1024*timedelta),2)
          speedout=round((bout-lastbout)/(1024*timedelta),2)
          lastbin, lastbout = bin, bout
          a.set_text(str(speedin))+'KB/s'
          xx,yy=a.get_size()
          b.set_position(int((300-xx)/2),int((100-yy)/2)+100)
def parseKeyPress(self, event):
    #Parses the keyboard as this is called by the stage object
    if event.keyval == clutter.keysyms.q:
        #If "q" is pressed, quit
        clutter.main_quit()
    elif event.keyval == clutter.keysyms.q:
        #if "r" is pressed, make object red
        self.set_color(red)
    elif event.keyval == clutter.keysyms.g:
        #if "g" is pressed, make object green
        self.set_color(blue)
    elif event keyval.syms == clutter.keysyms.b:
        #if "b" is clicked, make object blue
        self.set_color(blue)
    elif event.keyval -- clutter.keysyms.0:
        #if "0" is clicked, make object black
        self.set_color(black)
    print 'Event Processed', event.keyval
stage = clutter.Stage()
stage.set_size(300,200)
stage.set_color(blue)
stage.connect('key-press-event',parseKeyPress)
intext=clutter.Text()
intext.set_font_name("Sans 30")
intext.set_color(green)
stage.add(intext)
outtext=clutter.Text()
outtext.set_font_name("Sans 30")
outtext.set_color(red)
stage.add(outtext)
stage.show_all()
t=clutter.TImeline()
t.set_duration(5000)
t.set_loop(True)
t.connect('completed',updatespeed, intext, outtext)
t.start()
clutter.main()
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong! This is the output when I try to execute it through my terminal. My first mistake was not adding a closing bracket. Right now, by the way, the mistake is in the code in line 40:

```
    elif event keyval.syms == clutter.keysyms.b:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Looks like you've missed a full stop between `even` and `keyval`. That will definitely give a syntax error.

Comment: Great Thanks! No more issues! Except for the fact that now it says that there is now module named cluttergtk. I copied and pasted the imports off of the instructions to install clutter!

Comment: That's a separate problem. Did you install cluttergtk?

Comment: Yes! I have whole folder that I installed and compiled earlier for pyclutter-gtk earlier.